# Using custom fonts. What have I missed?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to use a custom font on a TextView in **Xamarin C#**

I have the file `coopbl.ttf` (don't judge me, this was just to see if it worked!)

I have placed it in the following location `root/Assets/Font/coopbl.ttf` and marked Build Action to AndroidAssist

My XML looks as follows:

```
<TheKey.Classes.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="font"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:id="@+id/customFont"
custom:customFont="Font/coopbl.ttf"/>
```

When I call `Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "Font/coopbl.ttf");` I get the following exception:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found Font/coopbl.ttf at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw

I have followed much of the pattern used by Cheesebaron here, including the `TextView.cs` class: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.FontSample.

What have I missed?

**Update based on comments**

I tried the following with no luck, still seeing the same error:

- Renamed `Font` directory to `font` then to `fonts` and then even tried `Fonts` for completeness
- Removed `Font/` from the method call

In Visual Studio, the `Assets` folder is located in the root of the project when a new Xamarin project is created, it is at the same level as `Resources`.

Comment: You need to add the folder `font` to your `assets` resource directory in your project and drop your `coopbl.tff` file into it.

Comment: @zgc7009: As the 3rd line in my question?

Comment: Not tried it, but could it be the case?  Try making everything lower case(including folder names)

Comment: I don't think you need the "Font/" part in your string. [See here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/#Android)

Comment: I am not sure if it makes a difference, but usually I think the folder is called "fonts" not "Font".....maybe this is a requirement, but it´s just an assumption...

Comment: other possible problem, are you sure you placed it in the correct hierachy? the asset folder must be under the main not under res.....

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not explicit enough, I meant more so what @Opiatefuchs is getting at with his last comment. Are you sure that it is an appropriately placed `assets` as a `resource directory`? I don't think resource directories are in root, but are in the main directory of your android application unless Xamarin handles it differently. Also, good call again from Opiatefuchs that it is normally `fonts` I missed that :P

Comment: @zgc7009, Opiatefuchs, ChrisStillwell, Blueberry, thanks for your time, I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you already tried clean / deleting your bin folder and try a full rebuild?

Comment: Do you know what, that solved it. I've been caught out with similar before. I guess I don't learn LOL.

Comment: @tallpaul: It would be helpful to answer your own question if you have solved it.